# Create Week Variable Based on Date Time Variable

Tags: sas

Simple question, I think.

I have a checkin_date_time variable in a database with thousands of unique records.

Database

```
   ID             checkin_date_time 
   1             January 01, 2019 11:36:50
   2             January 01, 2019 11:36:55 
   ....
   60000         December 31, 2019 11:36:50
   60001         December 31, 2019 11:36:55
```

I would like to create a 'week' variable based on the checkin_date_time variable. So for example 'January 01, 2019 11:36:55' would equal week 1 and 'December 31, 2019 15:16:57' would equal week 52.

Desired Output

```
   ID             datetime                         Week
   1             January 01, 2019 11:36:50          1
   2             January 01, 2019 11:36:55          1
   ....
   60000         December 31, 2019 11:36:50         52
   60001         December 31, 2019 11:36:55         52
```

I tried using the following code but its saying my

```
 data testl;
 set ed_tat;
 week=week(checkin_date_time);
 run;
```

NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.

Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).

Comment: Post your exact errors. The errors are informative and usually indicate exactly where the issue is, ie find that line, column n your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Week operates on a date variable, use DATEPART() to get the date first and then determine the week.

```
week = week(datepart(checkin_date_time));
```

Comment: thanks @reeza, so it appears my error was not including the 'datepart'!

Comment: Yes, because you have a datetime variable, not a date variable so you first need to convert it to a date.